# Remove duplicate sequences of events in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I'm looking for a way in SQL (I'm using [Presto](https://prestodb.io/)) to gather unique sequences of events. I need to remove duplicate events that are right next to each other, always taking the latest one.

So for instance, in this dataset, we see duplicate B.

| id | event | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10:01 AM |
| 1 | B | 10:02 AM |
| 1 | B | 10:03 AM |
| 1 | A | 10:04 AM |
| 1 | B | 10:05 AM |

I'm looking for the output like this (notice how the duplicate B at 10:02 is removed since it's followed by another B?)

| id | event | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10:01 AM |
| 1 | B | 10:03 AM |
| 1 | A | 10:04 AM |
| 1 | B | 10:05 AM |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gaps-and-islands approach - find where the value changes (using [`lag` window function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lag)) and then do a cumulative sum to assign groups:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(id, event, time) AS (
    VALUES (1, 'A', '10:01 AM'),
    (1, 'B', '10:02 AM'),
    (1, 'B', '10:03 AM'),
    (1, 'A', '10:04 AM'),
    (1, 'B', '10:05 AM')
)

-- query
select id, 
    max(event) event, 
    max(time) time
from (
    select id, 
        event, 
        time, 
        sum(if(event != prev_event, 1, 0)) over(partition by id order by time) grp
    from (
        select *, 
            lag(event) over(partition by id order by time) as prev_event
        from dataset)
)
group by id, grp;
```

Output:

| id | event | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10:01 AM |
| 1 | B | 10:03 AM |
| 1 | A | 10:04 AM |
| 1 | B | 10:05 AM |